# Issues with SQL ERROR: subquery returned more than 1 row

Tags: sql, select, row

I am trying to devise an SQL statement where I am getting said error in the subject.  I understand that there are other topics on this error but have not seen any regarding my specific problem where I am trying to get a value based off multiple rows. I would appreciate any insight.  Here are my simplified Tables and SQL statement.

**TableA**:

```
member_id
----------
1
2
3
4
```

**TableB**:

```
user_id  field_id  value
------------------------
1        1         red
2        2         red
1        2         blue
4        1         red
2        1         blue 
3        1         blue
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(member_id) 
FROM TableA 
WHERE member_id = (SELECT b.user_id 
                   FROM TableB b 
                   INNER JOIN TableB a on a.user_id = b.user_id 
                   WHERE a.field_id = '1' ANd a.value = 'red' 
                     AND b.field_id = '2' ANd b.value = 'blue')
```

I am trying to select the `member_id` from table A as the `user_id` in Table B where in table B the user's field_id(1) = red and the same user's field_id(2) = blue.

Therefore the select statement should return the member_id with id = 1.

Comment: Do you get an error? I think you could get what you want by simply putting distinct into your subquery and erasing the outer query altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the query you had for the sub select and just `JOIN` tableA.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableB b1 
INNER JOIN TableB b2 on b1.user_id = b2.user_id 
INNER JOIN tableA a ON a.member_id  = b1.user_id
WHERE b2.field_id = '1' ANd b2.value = 'red' 
  AND b1.field_id = '2' ANd b1.value = 'blue'
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouping by `user_id`, you could try counting the hits and filter accordingly:

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM tableB
  GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN field_id = 1 AND value = 'red'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
     AND SUM(CASE WHEN field_id = 2 AND value = 'blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

And how about another variation:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableA AS a
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableB b where b.user_id = a.member_id AND B.field_id = 1 AND B.value = 'red')
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableB b where b.user_id = a.member_id AND B.field_id = 2 AND B.value = 'blue')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner query is doing an inner join of TableB to itself. This is almost never necessary.

If you want records from tableA where the `user_id = member_id`, and `field_ID = 1` when `value = red`, or `field_id = 2` when `value = blue`, you'll want something more like this:

```
SELECT distinct(member_id) 
FROM TableA inner join TableB on user_id = member_id 
WHERE (field_id = '1' AND value = 'red')
   OR (field_id = '2' AND value = 'blue')
```

If you want only records where they have both, just throw a distinct on your original inner query.

Comment: I think your logic is flawed and the person indeed needed the two joins. If he puts AND, the condition (field_id='1' and somethingelse) and (field_id='2' and somethingother) will never be true.

Comment: Good point. Your comment on his original post is also correct.